# Error using pip install for arcpy: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement arcpy...."

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7

In my command line I typed

```
python -m pip install arcpy
```

to install arcpy. I got this error message in return:

"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement arcpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for arcpy"

I'm using python 2.7. What to do?

Comment: ArcPy is a part of ArcGIS.  You can't install it like an Internet extension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`arcpy` ships with Esri's ArcGIS software package. It is neither free nor open source and, even if you were able to obtain it without an ArcGIS license, you would not be able to use it as it has a built-in license checker.

If you *do* have an ArcGIS license, but are trying to use `arcpy` in a Python environment other than the Esri default, I would recommend doing so with Anaconda, using a setup like the one described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/134230/4681). **Edit:** arcpy can now be installed directly in any Anaconda environment with `conda install -c esri arcpy` (and yes, it still requires an ArcGIS license).

If you don't have an ArcGIS license, there are several free and/or open source alternatives available, which other users here know much more about than I do.

Comment: For me, it turned out to be a 32 vs. 64 bit problem--thank you.

Comment: You can use GDAL python library as an open source alternative