# Error installing Rasterio in PyCharm and in CMD Line

Tags: installation, rasterio

Error installing Rasterio in PyCharm (Settings > Project Interpreter)

```
Collecting rasterio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/d5/6cad936ff9beb89e79b1dae946f3097c70f7ab71cda5a9e356aec2e9ce9b/rasterio-1.0.8.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    INFO:root:Building on Windows requires extra options to setup.py to locate needed GDAL files. More information is available in the README.
    ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\rasterio\
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Same error when trying to install in command line; following is cmd line entry:

```
cd C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\Scripts
pip freeze
pip install rasterio
```

Here's the command line return:

```
Collecting rasterio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/d5/6cad936ff9beb89e79b1dae946f3097c70f7ab71cda5a9e356aec2e9ce9b/rasterio-1.0.8.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    INFO:root:Building on Windows requires extra options to setup.py to locate needed GDAL files. More information is available in the README.
    ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\starb\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dw_0ma\rasterio\
```

I can't find the gdal-config path. I guessed gdal-data and added that to Windows Environments, but no dice. I installed GDAL following these instructions: https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows

Comment: First, I would use a standard installation of Python, rather than the ArcGIS install. Do you have QGIS installed on your machine, complete with the GDAL tools?

Comment: I would highly recommend using Anaconda to manage your Python environments and keep this separate from Arc's

Comment: @gberard, I'm only using python for ArcGIS work, so would I have to duplicate libraries then? (newbie)

Comment: Yes, you'd have totally separate environments with a separate interpreter and everything.  So for a given project you could use whatever version of Python with whatever version of a particular library.  This is my preferred route, since Arc needs a specific version of certain libraries (e.g. numpy).  If you update those trying to get other packages to work you can bork everything.  I never got GDAL to fully install in Arc's environment back when I tired, FWIW.  Basically if you need to use ArcPy then you're somewhat limited with what else you can install

Comment: I have the same issue, trying to install in non-ArcGIS python installation, any ideas how to install?

Comment: @Symbionte see if either of these help you: https://my.usgs.gov/confluence/display/EGIS/Using+Anaconda+modules+from+the+ESRI+python+environment or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119503/getting-arcpy-to-work-with-anaconda