# arcgisscripting module not found in Python 3.5 in Spyder IDE

Tags: arcpy, spyder

I am running ArcGIS Pro 2.2 and I have cloned my conda environment from Python command prompt. When I activate this environment and attempt to run Python 3.5 from the terminal, I can load arcpy as the cloned environment runs the python located at `'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\python.exe'`. However, Spyder links to the python installed in the cloned environment and I get the following traceback:

```
File "<ipython-input-4-f7f77bfeaa96>", line 1, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp

  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp

  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._base import *

  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have followed the directions located [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119503/getting-arcpy-to-work-with-anaconda) and [here](https://my.usgs.gov/confluence/display/EGIS/Using+Anaconda+modules+from+the+ESRI+python+environment#UsingAnacondamodulesfromtheESRIpythonenvironment-4)ConfigureArcGISpythontoseeAnacondaenvironmentandviceversa), and the paths mirror a previous installation of ArcGIS Pro 2.0 from which I can use Spyder and arcpy together.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: It's easier to just install Spyder into your cloned conda environment.  Run "Start Menu\Programs\ArcGIS\ArcGIS Pro\Python Command Prompt" (not Python Interactive Terminal) and type `conda install spyder`.  Then use that Spyder to run ArcGIS Pro arcpy scripts.

Comment: That is how I installed spyder. I am editing my question to add some more information.

Comment: You might be missing ArcGISPro.pth, copy from
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages to your env, Lib\sitepackages.

Comment: This might be more of a conda issue, so I have posted the question on Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268949/specify-path-to-specific-python-executable-using-conda. This question could be put on hold.

Comment: My cloned ArcGIS Pro 2.2 env is in "`%LocalAppData%\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone`". I just ran `conda install spyder` from my activated env and then from the same command prompt, ran `spyder` which opened and I was able to `import arcpy` from the spyder IPython console.  My clone runs the python in the env, i.e "`%LocalAppData%\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\python.exe`" not from the original env, so I don't know how you've managed that.

Comment: Did you clone your ArcGIS Pro 2.2 env from the python command prompt, or using the Python Package Manager within the Pro GUI? I cloned from the python command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Okay all,

I think that I figured out the problem. When I cloned the ArcGISPro environment, I used the following: `conda create --clone arcgispro-py3 --name clone`. This led to the creation of a clone located at `%LocalAppData%\conda\conda\envs\clone`. This is not the default location that ArcGISPro uses. When I clone using `conda create --clone arcgispro-py3 --name %LocalAppData%\ESRI\conda\envs\clone` is creates the cloned environment at `%LocalAppData%\ESRI\conda\envs`, which is the default location. I am now able to use arcpy from within spyder.