# Using sublime text for Arcgis or Arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-2.7

I have installed python 27 in one directory c:\program files\python27 and arcgis 10.2 in another directory c:\program files\arcgis, and within this folder there is c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy. After opening up the arcgis map interface I can activate python IDLE and start using python commands.

But what if I want to use sublime text for arcpy instead?

Comment: I would advise using the Python distribution that is installed by default when you install ArcGIS. This way, all of the dependencies and versions will be correct (e.g. ArcGIS requires a specific numpy version). This should also solve your sublime text issue.

Answer (score 1):

to second what Aaron said, unless you need additional modules beyond the distribution included with ArcGIS, it's likely simpler to stick with one.
In either case, i don't see why you can't use sublime - or any text editor for that matter. After you save your script, simply open a command prompt (start -> cmd) and change directories to the location of your script `cd myDirectory`. Then use `python myScript.py`.
This will at least run one version of python - which version may depend on which one was installed last. But, typing `python` and hitting enter should give some indication which version you are using (python, or the distribution that is included with arcGIS).

there are several posts, but perhaps starting [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86850/how-to-make-a-separate-python-installation-that-can-call-arcgis-arcpy) and [perhaps another](https://pymorton.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/using-arcpy-with-anaconda/) regarding how to install other python distributions and get them to work with arcpy.