# Creating and calling virtual environment to run ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, pycharm

I'm getting a new computer and am trying to set up my virtual environments the right way. In the past, I've just been using PyCharm and running everything through "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6" so it's a miracle I haven't broken ArcPy yet on my old computer.

I'm setting up virtual environments for:

1. just ArcPy with ArcMap (so, Python 2.7); and
2. Python 3.x for GDAL and other things

I'm following @CurtisPrice’s [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86850/making-separate-python-installation-that-can-call-arcpy/) to [Making separate Python installation that can call ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/86850/115) to set up virtual environments.

There is a simple example below, where I am writing and running a .py script in PyCharm.

Do I now just call @CurtisPrice's *.py file to set the virtual environment?

```
usercustomize.py   ## is this how I set the virtual environment???
import arcpy

myshp = r'C:\Users\name\path\myfile.shp'
arcpy.AddField_management(myshp, "new_field", "SHORT")
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a similar setup to the one you described. I ended up installing the latest Python version (3.7) using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/). I found it to be the most straightforward to install Python packages and manage environments. For example, to install `gdal` you just have to run `conda install gdal`.

This way, I had two Python installations: the one that comes with ArcGIS 10.x (2.7) and the one I downloaded from Anaconda (3.7). To change the Python version I was using in PyCharm, I would just go to File > Settings... > Project: Project Name > Project Interpreter and choose one of the two Python installations depending if I needed ArcPy or if I needed other packages such as `gdal`.

On an additional note, the best advantage Anaconda probably has is the simplicty it offers to [create and manage new environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). With just one command you can create a new environment inside `conda` to use a specific version of Python and specific versions of packages (*e.g.* `gdal`, `numpy`, `scipy`). Then, to use this environment from PyCharm you just have to change the interpreter the same way I described above. (All environments are stored in `C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs` if you installed everything in the default folder.)