# Using conda and ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, conda, arcgis-10.8

Is there a way to use ArcPy without having ArcGIS Pro?

I am currently using ArcMap 10.8 and am trying to set up a conda environment that is compatible. However, I'm having trouble finding the esri packages I need to install and all tutorials I find are made specifically for ArcGIS Pro.

I found a couple solutions here: [Making separate Python installation that can call ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86850/making-separate-python-installation-that-can-call-arcpy),
but they're pretty dated. I am considering trying the provided script:

```
try:
    import archook #The module which locates arcgis
    archook.get_arcpy()
    import arcpy
except ImportError:
    # do whatever you do if arcpy isnt there.
```

but if there is an esri-approved way to import arcpy without Pro, I'd prefer that. I just can't find it.

Comment: Do you mean anaconda python? For what purpose?

Comment: I am wanting to import arcpy processes while coding. I primarily use Anaconda Python.

Comment: 10.8 ArcMap/ArcCatalog are 2.7 32-bit Python (with some 2.7 64-bit background support).  The installation isn't really compatible with conda, so they really never tried.  ArcGIS Server has Python 3 support, so that's your best chance without Pro, though it's likely to be very Pro-like.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'll check out ArcGIS Server. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: there are 2 python environments included with server, there's a python 2.7 found at `c:\python27\ArcGIS10.9x64` (on windows). There's also python 3.x,  easiest way to get at that one is with windows start button to pick **Python3 Command Prompt**.  The python 3.x is deployed using a conda environment. wrt arcpy, they're very similar between ArcMap and Pro (with some known exceptions, primarely `arcpy.mapping`).

Comment: @gotchula I understood the first part of your comment but the second part is confusing for me. I found ArcGIS10.8.1 but what should I do to integrate Anaconda with ArcGIS python? Please explain a bit more.